# Iterate through values stored in a vector

Tags: r, loops, vector

Have code below where I am trying to pick out the unique zone names then iterate through , however when I run it it just prints out 1 line.

This is my code:

```
 ZonelistName<-unique(temp[c("zone")])
  
  #this is where the LSD for the zone will be
  
  for (p in c(ZonelistName)) {
    print(p)
  }
```

Which prints out:

```
# > [1] 3 2 5 1



   dput(head(ZonelistName))
structure(list(zone = c(3, 2, 5, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

sorry i cant reproduce it as i dont know what that object is

Comment: Did you look at the contents of ZonelistName?  Say with `head(ZonelistName)` ?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What exactly is `temp`?

Comment: Give us output of `dput(head(ZonelistName))`.

Comment: I think what you need is `ZonelistName <- unique(temp$zone)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you might need `unlist` rather than `c`

```
for (p in unlist(ZonelistName)) {
  print(p)
}
```

or

```
for (p in ZonelistName$zone) {
  print(p)
}
```

which gives

```
[1] 3
[1] 2
[1] 5
[1] 1
```